# Installation progress status messages from InstallShield Suite Installer

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2016

I have my own Updater.exe that launches the InstallShield Suite Installer (which  is embedded with two other InstallShield MSIs). I would like to get the installation progress status messages from Suite Installer and show in my Updater.exe UI.

Is it possible to poll/ping the installer to get the installation status message? (Like staging, installing msi1, installing msi2, configuring, install complete).

I am using .NET Framework 4.5+ in my installer as a prerequisite, Installshield version 2016, wiX toolset for custom actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield 2016 do not have any out of the box features to get the status messages while the installation is in progress.

I end up writing my own tool to monitor installshield property values in debug log that generates with debuglog parameters.

InstallShield Installer Debug Logs:

> syntax: Installer.exe /debuglog"logfilepath"
>
> example: installer.exe /debuglog"c:\users\test.user\desktop\debuglog.log"

InstallShield sets three different status types viz; 'ISProgressSummary', 'ISInstallStatus' and 'ISParcelStatus' and logs into debug logs.

Sample installshield debug log entries are:

> 9-23-2019[10:40:56 AM]: Engine: property 'ISProgressSummary' value now 'The program features you selected are being installed.'
>
> 9-23-2019[10:41:12 AM]: Engine: property 'ISInstallStatus' value now 'Installing package Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Update 4 Redistributable Package (x86)'
>
> 9-23-2019[10:41:17 AM]: Engine: property 'ISParcelStatus' value now 'Computing space requirements'

Below C# code monitors debug log and invokes an event handler. You create an object of below class and send the 'statusType' you want to monitor. statusType can be ISProgressSummary, ISInstallStatus, ISParcelStatus

```
public class LogFileMonitorLineEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Line { get; set; }
}

public class LogFileMonitor
{
    public EventHandler<LogFileMonitorLineEventArgs> OnLine;

    readonly string _path;
    readonly string _delimiter;
    readonly string _statusType;

    Timer _timer;

    long _currentSize;
    bool _isCheckingLog;

    protected bool StartCheckingLog()
    {
        lock (_timer)
        {
            if (_isCheckingLog)
                return true;

            _isCheckingLog = true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void DoneCheckingLog()
    {
        lock (_timer)
            _isCheckingLog = false;
    }

    public LogFileMonitor(string path, string delimiter = "\n", string statusType = "")
    {
        _path = path;
        _delimiter = delimiter;
        _statusType = statusType;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _currentSize = new FileInfo(_path).Length;

        _timer = new Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += CheckLog;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void CheckLog(object s, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!StartCheckingLog()) return;

        try
        {
            var newSize = new FileInfo(_path).Length;

            if (_currentSize == newSize)
                return;

            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                sr.BaseStream.Seek(_currentSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var newData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                if (!newData.EndsWith(_delimiter))
                {
                    if (newData.IndexOf(_delimiter, StringComparison.Ordinal) == -1)
                    {
                        newData = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var pos = newData.LastIndexOf(_delimiter, StringComparison.Ordinal) + _delimiter.Length;
                        newData = newData.Substring(0, pos);
                    }
                }

                string[] lines = newData.Split(new[] { _delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                string lastInstallStatus = string.Empty;

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(_statusType))
                    {
                        lastInstallStatus = line;
                        OnLine?.Invoke(this, new LogFileMonitorLineEventArgs { Line = lastInstallStatus });
                    }
                }
            }

            _currentSize = newSize;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        DoneCheckingLog();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer?.Stop();
    }
}
```